# Default settings file does not exist - during installation (docker setup)

Tags: docker, drupal

I'm trying to setup Drupal site locally with docker. Using docker image 9.1.6-apache-buster from:

https://hub.docker.com/_/drupal

Running it on MacOs Mojave on Docker Desktop

My docker-compose.yml file looks like this:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mysqlRoot
      MYSQL_DATABASE: drupal_db
      MYSQL_USER: drupal
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: drupal

  drupal:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: drupal:9.1.6-apache-buster
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: drupal_db
      MYSQL_USER: drupal
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: drupal
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mysqlRoot

    volumes:
      - ./modules:/var/www/html/modules
      - ./sites:/var/www/html/sites
      - ./themes:/var/www/html/themes
volumes:
  db_data: {}
```

Installation goes well until I reach "requirements" installation step. Then I get errors:

```
The default settings file does not exist.
The Drupal installer requires that the ./sites/default/default.settings.php file must not be deleted or modified from the original download.
```

and

```
The Drupal installer requires that you create a ./sites/default/settings.php as part of the installation process. Copy the ./sites/default/default.settings.php file to ./sites/default/settings.php. More details about installing Drupal are available in INSTALL.txt.
```

https://snipboard.io/HAmU1o.jpg

Directories are created and I can see them on mac side, but they are empty?! Not a single file there:

```
modules
sites
  default
   files
themes
```

I guess it's some permissions problem?

Comment: Instead of building everything from scratch, have you considered already existing solutions, such as [DDEV](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) or [Lando](https://docs.lando.dev/)? They let you set up a Drupal site locally in few moments, are customizable, have standard tools such as xdebug or drush already build-in and are well documented. If you'll use DDEV (which I prefer) I suggest to enable the nfs mount system, on MacOs really improve the performance - the necessary steps are clearly explained in the docs.

Comment: @Giuseppe those are official docker images for drupal. Also I tried almost identical setup, but with WordPress and it works like a charm. So must be that some small tweak is needed there.

Answer (score 2):

I found the default.settings.php file in a subdirectory under /opt/drupal. From there I had to copy it to the expected location in var/www/html/sites/default, change the owner to www-data, and copy it to settings.php as well:

```
cp /opt/drupal/web/core/assets/scaffold/files/default.settings.php /var/www/html/sites/default/
chown www-data:www-data /var/www/html/sites/default/default.settings.php
cp /var/www/html/sites/default/default.settings.php /var/www/html/sites/settings.php
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue, I had to create a settings.php file and copy in from the docker-compose.yml:

settings.php:

```
$databases['default']['default'] = [
    'database' => getenv('MYSQL_DATABASE'),
    'username' => getenv('MYSQL_USER'),
    'password' => getenv('MYSQL_PASSWORD'),
    'host' => getenv('MYSQL_HOST'),
    'prefix' => '',
    'port' => '3306',
    'namespace' => 'Database\\Driver\\mysql',
    'driver' => 'mysql',
];
```

The docker file:

```
 volumes:
      - ./modules:/var/www/html/modules
      - ./profiles:/var/www/html/profiles
      - ./themes:/var/www/html/themes
      - ./sites:/var/www/html/sites
      - "./settings.php:/var/www/html/sites/default/default.settings.php"
      - "./settings.php:/var/www/html/sites/default/settings.php"
```

The installation was completed successfully. I noticed that the `/var/www/html/sites/default/settings.php` was amended with new database settings. Which means that Drupal's installer just needed that file to exist in that location in order to proceed. Maybe it is a bug to address on their side.